# Will a improper integral diverge if the integrand diverges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

If I have a improper integral: $$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x
$$ Where the integrand $f$ is undefined at one of the limits a or b (or both limits).
And I'm being asked whether or not the integral converges or diverges, but I don't need to know the value if it converges.

Is it enough to check whether the limit of the integrand $$
\lim _{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x)
$$ exists (if a is the point it's not defined)?

It makes intuitive sense that the integral will diverge if the integrand is divergent at one of the interval endpoints. Or do I have to try to calculate the integral and show that it diverges using this approach: $$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x=\lim _{k \rightarrow a^{+}} \int_{k}^{b} f(x) d x=\lim _{k \rightarrow a^{+}}[F(x)]_{k}^{b}
$$

Comment: divergence of the integrand alone says NOTHING about the corresponding integral. What is $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$? What is $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$? Also, what is $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{1}{t}\,dt$? What is $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo okay I see. That's a good example. I think I will forget my intuition and just calculate the improper integrals looking forward ;-) Thank you for your response.